# Scene Builder with JFX 11 imports

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder, gluon

I have a jar with custom controls. When it is built under Java 10 I'm able to import it to scene builder and access my custom controls. When I build it using Java 11, the list of controls to import is empty.

Does anyone know if there's something special I need to configure to handle this? Or do I need to wait for Scene Builder to be updated? With gluon apparently taking on a stewardship role of JavaFX I had expected this to work out of the box.

Comment: Scene Builder 11 (RC1) has been [released](https://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/#download), can you try it and provide feedback if it still doesn't work for you?

Comment: @JoséPereda the RPM packages for Scene Builder 10 and 11 have not been digitally signed, so the installer halts with a warning. Surely Gluon should be signing these installer files to reduce the risk of malware masquerading as legitimate software.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Mac and Windows installers are signed afaik. Those should be signed as well. It is still an RC, so that should be fixed for the final release.

Comment: @JoséPereda good to hear, but so far the RPM for Scene Builder 10 is not signed either, and that is (so far as I understand) a stable release. It sounds as though the Debian packages  are probably signed, but the RPM packages (which are required for OpenSUSE) are not. I've used the "Contact Us" form on the Gluon website to ask for the RPM installer packages to be digitally signed, and I'm hoping they're able to do this very soon.